# Slideshow links, sliding, buttons

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, css

The thing is  http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/2/

```
     $(".image").wrap("<a href=\"link.html\"></a>");
```

I want to put these var on links so when pic changes it has link for each picture.
And with these code my buttons dont work on my computer bur here in fiddle they work ?! strange.

And it is constantly changing my 1st picture with these Interval function.

Can somebody help!

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the images like this:

```
var image = [
    {src: "pretend this is an image", link: "http://www.google.com"},
    {src: "and lets pretend this is another", link: "http://www.yahoo.com"},
    {src: "and one more for show", link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
];
```

Then you can alter your html() method to pass in the `image.src` and `image.link` properties when generating the markup.

Comment: I am a beginner so ita bit hard to undesrtand what are you saying :/, the part with "Then you can alter your html() method to pass in the image.src and image.link properties when generating the markup."

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code:

HTML

```
<a href="link1.html" class="picture">pretend this is an image</a>
<div class="bullet">click here to change manually</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () { //change this to setInterval to make it constantly flip through rather than one time
        change();
    }, 2400);
});

var image = [
    ["pretend this is an image", "link1.html"],
    ["and lets pretend this is another", "link2.html"],
    ["and one more for show", "link3.html"]
];
var index = 1;

$(".bullet").click(function () {
    change();
});

function change() {
    if (index == 3) {
        index = 0;
    }
    $(".picture").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $(".picture").html(image[index][0]);
        $(".picture").attr("href", image[index][1]);
        $(".picture").fadeIn(1000);
        index++;
    });
}
```

Check your [**updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hTZWq/3/).

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: I posted the wrong code the code i use is this one http://jsfiddle.net/y8n3W/ and because i am new to this i dont really understand the "coding" yet.